# Choosing a line delimiter in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-set that has '^A' as the column delimiter and '^B' as the line delimiter. Currently when I try to read this in, everything is read in as a new column header because pandas is not recognizing that there is an end to the first line. I am just using a simple pandas read_csv statement. Here it is;

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.dat', sep='^A', engine='python')
```

Could this be something to do with the fact that it is a `.dat` file?

I cant find any literature online that talks about how pandas can deal with line delimiters.......which seems odd.

Comment: I don't think this is supported, you'd have to parse our file first and pre-process it and change the '^B' to new line character so it's compatible

Comment: Could it be that it is just your editor that displays `^A` and `^B` as a replacement character for some binary values that cannot be displayed?

Comment: @languitar This is possible but I still don't know what delimiters I should be using.

Comment: @EdChum Parsing the file is an option. I will take a look into that.

Answer (score -1):

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""h1^Ah2^Ah3^B111^A222^A333^B111^A222^A333^B111^A222^A333"""), 
            sep='\^B',engine='python', header=None)

df = df.stack().to_frame()

df
Out[52]: 
                 0
0 0     h1^Ah2^Ah3
  1  111^A222^A333
  2  111^A222^A333
  3  111^A222^A333

df = df[0].str.split('\^A', expand=True)

df
Out[54]: 
       0    1    2
0 0   h1   h2   h3
  1  111  222  333
  2  111  222  333
  3  111  222  333

df.columns = df.iloc[0].tolist()

df
Out[69]: 
      h1   h2   h3
0 0   h1   h2   h3
  1  111  222  333
  2  111  222  333
  3  111  222  333

df = df[1:]

df
Out[71]: 
      h1   h2   h3
0 1  111  222  333
  2  111  222  333
  3  111  222  333
```

Comment: Hi @Boud. Could you provide a bit more color around this answer as I would like to mark it as accepted but there isn't much detail provided? Thanks